# How to generate a new table, alter schema within a script in Django? or a helper

Tags: django, attributes, entity-attribute-value

I would need to create a way to a user create a new table at backoffice. Why that?

The app I'm building have a lot of articles but each article has different attributes. So an article might belong to a group that have the same attributes. So It could be:

```
 table: generated_table_screens
 --------------------
 |size: integer      
 |size_label: string = "size"
 |article_id: integer


 table: generated_table_mouses
 ---------------------
 |optic_val: integer
 |optic_val_label: string = "optic value"
 |article_id: integer


 table: articles
 --------------------
 |id
 |code
 |description
 |price
```

I have to choose between this and EAV. What are the cons and pros? and how might I do this in Django, and treat the "generated_table_mouses" for example with a model? because the model is not created...

Comment: EAV approach would make sense for a standard SQL database since the pattern is well known and documented and the other option you suggest is vague and makes life hard. Other viable alternatives would be NoSQL I guess.

Comment: I think I cannot use a noSQL db. But the speed with EAV is very slow, from what I've read because of multiple join per row. In my case I would need to query about 100 items and each item have an average of 6 attributes.

Comment: What's your argument against noSQL?

Comment: I cannot use on most commercial hosting plans. And I don't even know how to install and if is possible. Depends by hosting I know...

Answer (score 2):

You probably should look into a document-orientated database like [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) or [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) for this purpose...
There is a branch of django called [django-nonrel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel) which specifically supports NoSQL databases.